# Datagrid I Can't refresh field

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, refresh

I can't refresh a field in my datagrid.

This is my `DataGrid`:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Dati_Viaggio}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectDati_Viaggio}" 
          Style="{DynamicResource ST_DataGrid}" 
          CellStyle="{DynamicResource St_DataGridCellStyle}"
          SelectionMode="Single"  Name="Dg_Dati" IsReadOnly="True"
          RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected">
```

This is the field in `DataGrid` that I want to refresh

```
<DataGridTextColumn x:Name="col_NumOrd" Binding="{Binding Path=NumOrd}"
                    Header="Num. Ord." Width="150"/>
```

And this is the property:

```
public ObservableCollection<Model_Ricerca_Dati_Viaggio> Dati_Viaggio { get; set; }
private Model_Ricerca_Dati_Viaggio _SelectDati_Viaggio;
public Model_Ricerca_Dati_Viaggio SelectDati_Viaggio
{
    get { return _SelectDati_Viaggio; }
    set
    {
        _SelectDati_Viaggio = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("SelectDati_Viaggio");
    }
}
```

Why if I write this code the `DataGrid` doesn't refresh the field?

```
SelectDati_Viaggio.NumOrd= "abcabc";
OnPropertyChanged("SelectDati_Viaggio");
```

Thank you.

Comment: Add [UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.updatesourcetrigger%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to your binding base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to refresh binding by redeclaring and re-query the collections and initialize to the datagrid, just tried this after several days of searching of solutions. If you get the idea.

```
server = mongoClient.GetServer();
database = server.GetDatabase("facultyDataAndSchedule");
collection = database.GetCollection<facultyData>("faculty");
var query = collection.FindAllAs<facultyData>()
    .SetFields(Fields.Include("facultyID", "term", "acadYear", "age",
    "program", "lastName", "firstName", "middleName", "dateOfBirth",
    "rank", "yearsOfTeachingS", "yearsOfTeachingO", "status", "services"));
// List<facultyData> resultList = query.ToList<facultyData>();
resultBinding = new ObservableCollection<facultyData>(query);
facultyDataGrid.ItemsSource = resultBinding;
try
{
    try
    {
        var entity = new facultyData
        {
            facultyID = facultyID_Textbox.Text.ToString(),
            term = termComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString(),
            age = int.Parse(age_TextBox.Text),
            acadYear = "2014-2015",
            firstName = firstName_TextBox.Text.ToString(),
            lastName = lastName_TextBox.Text.ToString(),
            middleName = middleName_TextBox.Text.ToString(),
            dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth_TextBox.Text.ToString(),
            program = "progra",
            rank = "gegs",
            services = "gegsg",
            status = "geh",
            yearsOfTeachingO = 1,
            yearsOfTeachingS = 1
        };
        collection.Insert(entity);
    }
    catch (FormatException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
    }
}
catch (MongoConnectionException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex);
}
var query1 = collection.FindAllAs<facultyData>()
    .SetFields(Fields.Include("facultyID", "term", "acadYear", "age",
    "program", "lastName", "firstName", "middleName", "dateOfBirth",
    "rank", "yearsOfTeachingS", "yearsOfTeachingO", "status", "services"));
// List<facultyData> resultList = query.ToList<facultyData>();
resultBinding = new ObservableCollection<facultyData>(query1);
facultyDataGrid.ItemsSource = resultBinding;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think here:

```
<DataGridTextColumn x:Name="col_NumOrd" Binding="{Binding Path=NumOrd}"/>
```

You binding to `NumOrd` but here:

```
SelectDati_Viaggio.NumOrd= "abcabc";
OnPropertyChanged("SelectDati_Viaggio");
```

Notifing `SelectDati_Viaggio`, you need to notify `NumOrd`

```
SelectDati_Viaggio.NumOrd= "abcabc";
OnPropertyChanged("NumOrd");
```

than your control knows that property updated and refreshes

**EDIT:**
edit your `SelectDati_Viaggio` class

```
private string numOrd;
public string NumOrd 
{ 
   get { return numOrd; } 
   set { numOrd = value; OnPropertyChanged("NumOrd"); }
}
```

Hope helps!

Comment: Thank you very much for your replay, but doesn't refresh.

Comment: Is your OnPropertyChanged working correct? if works correct put OnPropertyChanged on setter of your NumOrd property @Alan392

Comment: Yes this OnPropertyChanged("SelectDati_Viaggio") work correct

Comment: If I check value in SelectDati_Viaggio, I see the new value (abcabc) but nothing refresh on datagrid

Comment: Do you have OnPropertyChanged("NumOrd") in setter of your NumOrd property? @Alan392

Comment: Yes, issue is OnPropertyChanged("NumOrd") I think.

Comment: Yes I have OnPropertyChanged("NumOrd") , but without solution

Comment: What do you mean by "without solution"? take a look on my edit @Alan392