# Datepicker disable or enable with checkbox in binding

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm

With a checkbox I want to enable or disable a datepicker, but my code doesn't work.

This is the xaml

```
<CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="32" 
    IsChecked="{Binding ABC}"
    Margin="108,91,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="191"/>


<DatePicker HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="32" 
    IsEnabled="{Binding ABC}"
    Margin="142,91,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="217"/>
```

And this is the property.

```
private bool _ABC {
    get;
    set;
}

public bool ABC {
    get {
        return _ABC;
    }
    set {
        _ABC = value;
    }
}

private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    MainWindow Vm = new MainWindow();
    this.DataContext = Vm;

    ABC = false;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Which is your checkbox?

Comment: The checkbox in my xaml

Comment: You aren't setting it to disabled anywhere in your code...

Comment: The setting is with binding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell it what property it's looking for, and who to get it from, like;

```
<CheckBox x:Name="TheCheckBox"
          HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="32" 
          IsChecked="{Binding ABC}"
          Margin="108,91,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="191"/>


<DatePicker HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="32" 
            IsEnabled="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=TheCheckBox}"
            Margin="142,91,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="217"/>
```

Hope this helps, cheers.

Comment: I'm sorry Chris, but can you help me for this issue pls?? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28739678/datagrid-i-cant-refresh-field You are very good ! ;-)

Comment: Sure thing, go check out my comment. :)